# SQL Server Management Studio Forms?

Tags: ms-access, ssms

I have an Access Database that I created and have already imported the database into SQL Server Management Studio 2008.  I also have forms that I created in Access 2013 and was wondering if there was a way to get the forms over to SQL Server Management Studio?
I asked my boss and he said we might have to create lists linked the SQL backend.  I'm not really sure what he means by that.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would create linked tables in Access to make use of the data in SQL Server.  SQL Server & Management Studio have no equivalent concept of the built in Forms Engine Access has.

Comment: SSMS has no forms at all like Access. Your boss - as he names lists - may think of Sharepoint. Again a completely different animal.

Answer (score 0):

If you link the SQL Tables to access you can continue using your access form. they will be able to reay and even write directly into the SQL tables. for this you need to create an ODBC handle.